# Finding adjacency matrix of a Mathematica's in-built graph?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to get the adjacency matrix of an in-built graph, say the dodecahedral graph. Naively using

```
AdjacencyMatrix[Dodecahedral]
```

doesn't give it to me.  Any other way to get it?

Comment: `Dodecahedral` is a symbol, not a graph. You want this: `d = GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"];
AdjacencyMatrix[d]`, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
am1 = GraphData["DodecahedralGraph", "AdjacencyMatrix"];
```

or

```
am2 = AdjacencyMatrix[GraphData["DodecahedralGraph"]];

am1 == am2
(* True *)

MatrixPlot[am1]
```

[image]